# Spring "redirect:" EL vulnerability?

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, el

I have a public-facing web application that uses Spring MVC (3.2.x) and Spring Security (3.1.x).  This morning I observed requests of the following form in our access logs:

`GET /MyWebAppPath/login.do?redirect:${Some URL-encoded EL code here}`

What bug or feature of Spring was this attempting to exploit?  Under what conditions would Spring (or some other code) evaluate that EL expression?

It looks like the `?redirect:` parameter was ignored for me, but it makes me nervous because I don't know where to look to verify that I'm not vulnerable.  All my Googling has turned up unrelated things (as best I can tell).

If that code inside the `${ }` had actually run, it would have attempted to dump the contents of `/etc/passwd` to the client.  (Thankfully it looks like it never did run.  Plus that file doesn't exist on our system.  And our Tomcat runs as a user with limited permissions.)

---

EDIT: Here is the actual code that was inside the `${ }`, after decoding and adding newlines to help readability:

```
#a=(new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(new java.lang.String[]{'cat','/etc/passwd'})).start(),
#b=#a.getInputStream(),
#c=new java.io.InputStreamReader(#b),
#d=new java.io.BufferedReader(#c),
#e=new char[50000],
#d.read(#e),
#matt=#context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse'),
#matt.getWriter().println(#e),
#matt.getWriter().flush(),
#matt.getWriter().close()
```

Comment: My guess is, and I certainly hope, that Spring would never evaluate a untrusted source like a query parameter. But then again, it's not even a valid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Es correcto, esta vulnerabilidad es exclusiva de Struts 2, y esta
>   documentada como CVE-2013-2251. No tienes de que preocuparte con
>   SPRING MVC.

That's right, this vulnerability is exclusive to Struts 2, and [is documented as CVE-2013-2251](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2013-2251).  You do not have to worry with Spring MVC.

Comment: I believe it's SO policy to respond to things in English. I've added a translation for you.